# symfony 3 form entity returning converting error

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

My form is returning the following error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE user_info SET
>   country_of_residence = ?, want_children = ?, salary = ? WHERE id = ?'
>   with params [{}, "a", "0", 22]:
>
> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Country could
>   not be converted to string

My UserInfoType:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/UserInfoType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType; 

class UserInfoType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('first_name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Prénom'))
            ->add('surname', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nom'))
            ->add('nationality', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nationalité'))
            ->add('country_of_residence', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Country',
                'choice_label' => 'name',                   
            ))
            ->add('maritial_status', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Votre statut maritial'))
            ->add('ethnique_origin', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Origine ethinique'))
            ->add('spoken_language', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Langues parlés'))
            ->add('children', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Possèdez vous des enfants'))
            ->add('want_children', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Désirez vous des enfants'))
            ->add('astrological_sign', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Votre signe astrologique'))
            ->add('education', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Votre niveau d\'étude'))
            ->add('profession', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Votre profession'))
            ->add('salary', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Votre salaire'))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Suivant'))
        ;

    }
```

My country entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Country
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="country")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CountryRepository")
 */
class Country
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="language", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $language;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set code
     *
     * @param string $code
     *
     * @return Country
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Country
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set language
     *
     * @param string $language
     *
     * @return Country
     */
    public function setLanguage($language)
    {
        $this->language = $language;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get language
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }
}
```

My profil controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/survey/{slug}", name = "survey_render" )
 */
public function renderSurvey($slug, Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();   
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user_info = $em->getRepository('ProfileBundle:UserInfo')->findOneBy(array('userId' => $user->getId()));
    if (!$user_info) {
        $user_info = new UserInfo();
        $user_info->setuserId($user->getId());
    }

    $user_pref = $em->getRepository('ProfileBundle:UserPreference')->findOneBy(array('userId' => $user->getId()));

    if (!$user_pref) {
        $user_pref = new UserPreference();
        $user_pref->setuserId($user->getId());
    }

    //$user_info = new UserInfo();

    switch ($slug) {
        case 'vos_infos':


            $form = $this->createForm(UserInfoType::class, $user_info );
            break;
        case 'votre_apparance':
            $form = $this->createForm(UserAppearanceType::class, $user_info);   
            break;
        case 'votre_style_vie':
            $form = $this->createForm(UserLifeStyleType::class, $user_info);    
            break;
        case 'ses_infos':
            $form = $this->createForm(UserPrefInfoType::class, $user_pref);
            break;
        case 'son_apparence':
            $form = $this->createForm(UserPrefAppearanceType::class, $user_pref);
            break;
        case 'son_style_vie':
            $form = $this->createForm(UserPrefLifeStyleType::class, $user_pref);
            break;
        case 'votre_quiz':
            $form = $this->createForm(UserLifeStyleType::class, $user_pref);
            break;
        default;
            echo 'Lien incorrect';
            break;
    }

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $form_data = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($form_data);
        $em->flush();
```

It seems that its trying to pass the whole entity to the form and not just the choice results.

Does anyone have an idea of what im doing wrong here?

Thx

Comment: How does your User or UserInfo Entity look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user_info is an entity do you have set the field country_of_residence as a onetoone relation on country entity ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the error I had in UserInfo.

I did not prepend @ORM and did not have the correct path to the Country entity ( it is not in the same namespace)

Before:

```
 /**
 * One Product has One Shipping.
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Country")
 * @JoinColumn(name="countryOfResidence", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $countryOfResidence;
```

After:

```
/**
     * One Product has One Shipping.
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Country")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="countryOfResidence", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $countryOfResidence;
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, @Yex777, this helped me find the answer more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same type of error. In my case it was an erroneous annotation in the 'owning' entity.

**Befor** (causes error):

```
/** 
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="RfpMatchBundle\Entity\Address", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true, unique=false)
 */
private $address;
```

**After**(fixed):

```
/** 
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="RfpMatchBundle\Entity\Address", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $address;`
```